# iOS scrolling tableView reusable cells reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working with `tableviews` in iOS. Reusable cells are reloaded when scrolling.

So, when updating -for example- `textfields` inside a cell, it disappears once scrolling over. I solved it by using an `Array` that saves all texts in all cells, but I wonder if there's a better way to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what your issue is what do you mean by: `it disappeared once scrolling over`?

Comment: Using Custom Cell class will solve it

Comment: @RASS when I scroll down, the cell disappears, so, i save its data inside an array, so that I can restore it when i scroll up again .

Comment: How are you implementing your table data source? Please post code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is how tableviews are meant to work!  The tableView is a display, not a store, and the reusable cells are only those currently displayed

You are right to use an array (or collection) to hold the data and just use the tableView to display it

Answer (score 1):

Using String array you have to store data of all textfields in tableview.
Use delegate methods of `UITableView` to implement more efficiently.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   MyCell * mc = (MyCell *) cell;
   names[indexPath.row] = mc.myTf.text;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   MyCell * mc = (MyCell *) cell;
   mc.myTf.text = names[indexPath.row];
}
```

Here, MyCell is the custom cell which has `UITextField`. name[] is the `NSString` array declared at class scope like `NSString * names[20]`.

Answer (score 0):

for memory management (to releasing memory) tableview remove cell memory which are not displaying in current screen its only keep those cell in memory which are currently displaying on screen so you have to store that text separate from tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You issue can be because of multithreading. If you are reloading data from a GCD operation or any NSOperation(different thread), then you have to use the below code to get the handle to main thread

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//perform the reload activity
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are doing right, as cells are reused you need to save your data, something like this -

1 . Have an array to hold your data.

2 . Update your array whenever you make any change in your textFields, so that your UI and data are in sync.

3. Use this array to populate your tableView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the cellIdentifier as unique. Then each cell created with unique identifier.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {   
        NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%dR%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

           //your logic here
        }


       return cell;
    }
```